# Viewing .doc and .docx documents with MathType equations on Linux

Tags: libreoffice, microsoft-word

Is there a way to view `.doc` and `.docx` documents with embedded MathType equations on Linux? When I try to open them with LibreOffice, I get blank boxes where the math is supposed to be - the same behavior I get on MS Word without MathType installed. But is Windows-only, so I can't install it on my Linux.

Is there a way to view those documents with the equations on Linux? I don't want to edit them, just to view them, and I don't mind if I have to convert the to some other format first, as long as the conversion can be done from Linux(I hate logging into Windows just to convert a document to PDF...)

Comment: Have you installed a real jdk (not gcj) and libreoffice-math ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but can Google Docs do this for you? You could view it in GDocs and then Download as PDF.

Comment: You might want to ask your question [here](http://ask.libreoffice.org/).

Comment: @Coren: I had them installed. I've also tried to update jdk to 1.7, but it didn't work.

Comment: @IdanArye then it's probably a bug then. Issuetracker of LibreOffice is probably a better place to ask your question